# With Apollo Server v4, how to access context on error handling?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I'm currently upgrading my Apollo Server to v4 in a Typescript project. I'm using the Express middleware to run it.

One thing that keeps me stuck right now is error handling.

I'd like to translate error message before sending it to the client. For this, I need to have access to the query context which contains user language.

In v3, I used to use `formatResponse` to do so.
Now in v4, `formatResponse` doesn't exist anymore and, according to the [migration guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration#formatresponse-hook) I have to use a plugin with a `willSendResponse`, like so:

```js
const responseFormattingPlugin: ApolloServerPlugin<MyContextType> = {
    async requestDidStart() {
        return {
            async willSendResponse(requestContext) {
                const {response, contextValue, errors} = requestContext;

                // Format reponse here. Unfortunately, errors is readonly                
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Thus, I tried to use the [formatError](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#formaterror) function, but unfortunately, I don't have access to the request context here so I can't do what I want.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but if you're trying to get past a block today, depending on how you're throwing errors, you can add additional information to the error itself. For example if you use `GraphQLError` you could do this:

```
throw new GraphQLError('some message', {
  extensions: { locale: context.local },
}
```

and then:

```
import { unwrapResolverError } from '@apollo/server/errors';

const server = new ApolloServer({
  formatError: (formattedError, error) => {
    if (formattedError?.extensions?.locale)) {
      return {
        ...formattedError,
        message: i18n(formattedError.message),
      };
    }
    return formattedError;
  },
  // ...
});
```

Obviously that's not super convenient to put everywhere, but you could make it easier by extending that as a class in your `context` object at the start of the request, and then just throw *that*.

```
const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    class LocalizedError extends GraphQLError {
      constructor(message: string, options: GraphQLErrorOptions = {}) {
        super(message, {
          locale: req.headers["accept-language"],
          ...options,
        });
      }
    }
    // throw new context.LocalizedError('some.i18n.key')
    return {
      ...whateverElse,
      LocalizedError,
    };
  },
  listen: { port: 4000 },
});
```

Comment: That really looks by the best (maybe the only one?) approach. I'm still trying to figure out the best way to do that with the minimum impact on my 5yo code base with `throws` about everywhere. Thanks for your input!